# Difference between sum and integral of $\frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2)^2}$

Tags: integration, summation, euler-maclaurin

I am trying to use the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)  to obtain the following difference:

\begin{align}
\Delta &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) - \int_0^\infty dx  f(x) \\
&= \frac{ f(\infty) - f(0) }{2} +
 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{p/2}\rfloor} \frac{ B_{2k}}{(2k)!} \left( f^{2k-1}(\infty) - f^{2k-1}(0) \right) + R_p
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2)^2}.
\end{align}

$f$ and all its derivatives of this function are zero at $x\to\infty$ and, moreover, since it is an even function, it's odd derivatives vanish at $x=0$. On the other hand, from the bound on $R_p$ given in Wikipedia, it seems $R_{p \to \infty} = 0$.  Therefore, I get
\begin{align}
\Delta = -\frac{f(0)}{2} = -\frac{1}{2 a^4}
\end{align}

However, Mathematica gives me exact expression for the sum, and the integral can also be carried out
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) &= \frac{\pi  a \left(\coth (\pi  a)+\pi  a \, \text{csch}^2(\pi  a)\right)-2}{4 a^4}, \qquad\qquad
\int_0^\infty dx \, f(x) = \frac{\pi}{4 a^3},
\end{align}
for which the difference seems not to agree with $\Delta$ calculated using Euler-Maclaurin. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: What makes you think that the results are different ? What does E-M tell you ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  It is $\Delta$ that I have computed ($\Delta = -1/a^4$). I don't think the difference between the last two expressions is equal to $\Delta$.

Comment: Indeed, but your $\Delta$ seems too simple to be true.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so I'm either doing something wrong with the Bernoulli terms, or the remainder is nonzero. But I can't spot my mistake.

Comment: $R_p$ doesn't tend to $0$.

Comment: @metamorphy yes I was wrong about $\zeta$. But do you not agree $f^{(p \to \infty)}(x) \to 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Of course I don't. If we expand $f(x+t)$ into a power series in $t$, it will have the radius of convergence equal to $R=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ (the distance to the closest singularity). Thus if $r>R$ then $r^n f^{(n)}(x)/n!$ cannot tend to zero. Roughly speaking, $f^{(n)}(x)$ grows factorially with $n$, for any $x$.

Comment: @metamorphy thank you for your comment. I had naively thought the remainder term generally approaches zero in general, which is not clearly the case here.

Comment: Anyway there's a very important [different view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Periodic_and_peak_functions) of the same effect.